# dispatch blocks return too early (Swift)

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to make sure that my cloud access completes before continuing with the main thread. I call downloadRecordsWithCompletion from within an alert action, so I'm in an enclosure.

```
        self.downloadRecordsWithCompletion() {
            error in

            println("out of alert")
            println("raceIdentities.count = \(raceIdentities.count)")
            println("raceTeams.count = \(raceTeams.count)")
            println("raceTasks.count = \(raceTasks.count)")

            self.misc()

        }
```

Here is the code called:

```
func downloadRecordsWithCompletion(completion: (error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    dispatch_async(GlobalUserInitiatedQueue) {
        var storedError: NSError!
        var downloadGroup = dispatch_group_create()

        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)
        self.cloudReadRaceIdentities(self.isMonitor)
        dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)

        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)
        self.cloudReadParameters()
        dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)

        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)
        self.cloudReadCheckpoints()
        dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)

        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)
        self.cloudReadTeams()
        dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)

        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)
        self.cloudReadTasks()
        dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)

/*
        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)
        self.cloudReadRaceIdentities(self.isMonitor)
        self.cloudReadParameters()
        self.cloudReadCheckpoints()
        self.cloudReadTeams()
        self.cloudReadTasks()
        dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)
*/

        dispatch_group_wait(downloadGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

        dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue) {
            //if let completion = completion {
                completion(error: storedError)
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I have tried, it always hits throws "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when hitting

```
println("raceIdentities.count = \(raceIdentities.count)")
```

because the code that is called from this line:

```
self.cloudReadRaceIdentities(self.isMonitor)
```

has not yet happened.

I tried the commented out code (without success) and also changed this line:

```
dispatch_async(GlobalUserInitiatedQueue) {
```

to this

```
dispatch_sync(GlobalUserInitiatedQueue) {
```

I've also moved the println statements outside the enclosure, with the same results.

Most of my information comes from raywenderlich.com on his Grand Central Dispatch Tutorial for Swift but obviously I'm missing something.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what does the error object contain?

Comment: I changed the call closure to add the following: println(error!.description) and the same error is thrown ("fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value") but now on this new println.

Comment: I agree, raceIdentities is nil when the println() is encountered because the call to cloudReadRaceIdentities has not completed. The issue is not with whether I unwrap an optional (error in this case) but why I even get to this point when I want to wait for the cloud operations to complete first.

Comment: Why don't you use NSOperation(Queue)? It has a much nicer interface to express dependencies.

Comment: I'll take a look at NSOperation, thanks. Still would like to know where I went wrong above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to either:

- Make your reader functions synchronous. Then you can also remove all the `dispatch_group` stuff (It does nothing anyways how you have it right now)
- Add a completion handler to your reader functions, in which you leave the `dispatch_group`

I would suggest using the first method, which would look something like this (after making your reader functions synchronous):

```
func downloadRecordsWithCompletion(completion: (error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    dispatch_async(GlobalUserInitiatedQueue) {

        self.cloudReadRaceIdentities(self.isMonitor)
        self.cloudReadParameters()
        self.cloudReadCheckpoints()
        self.cloudReadTeams()
        self.cloudReadTasks()

        dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue) {
            completion(error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The second method would look something like this (after adding a completion handler parameter to your reader functions):

```
func downloadRecordsWithCompletion(completion: (error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    dispatch_async(GlobalUserInitiatedQueue) {
        let downloadGroup = dispatch_group_create()

        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)
        self.cloudReadRaceIdentities(self.isMonitor) {
            dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)
        }

        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)
        self.cloudReadParameters() {
            dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)
        }

        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)
        self.cloudReadCheckpoints() {
            dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)
        }

        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)
        self.cloudReadTeams() {
            dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)
        }

        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)
        self.cloudReadTasks() {
            dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)
        }

        dispatch_group_wait(downloadGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

        dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue) {
            completion(error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Oh also this may not work (forget this above) because there's only 1 group but multiple points at which it could be left. So you probably want to use a `dispatch_semaphore` which waits until the it's been signaled n times like this:

```
func downloadRecordsWithCompletion(completion: (error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    dispatch_async(GlobalUserInitiatedQueue) {
        let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(5)

        self.cloudReadRaceIdentities(self.isMonitor) {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
        }

        self.cloudReadParameters() {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
        }

        self.cloudReadCheckpoints() {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
        }

        self.cloudReadTeams() {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
        }

        self.cloudReadTasks() {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
        }

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

        dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue) {
            completion(error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

But I still suggest making you're read functions synchronous, because you're already asynchronous in your method

Comment: Thank you. I've been pulling my hair out on this one.